# ¿Cómo obtener fechas consecutivas faltantes en MySql?

Tags: mysql

Tengo la tabla siguiente
nombre de la tabla : pruebafecha

```
id  -----fecha----
 1  2018/03/01 0:05
 2  2018/03/01 0:15
 3  2018/03/01 0:20
    --------------
```

Quisiera saber si existe algun procedure o un inner que busque todas las fechas que no estan registradas por ejemplo tengo 3 fechas registradas pero quiero hacer que muestre la que no este que seria 
 fecha 
 2018/03/01 0:10 no esta registrada en la base de datos pero quiero que muestre cuales no estan hay , espero que me entiendan.
cada 5 minutos incrementa la hora

gracias por su atencion

Comment: ¿Quieres que ese dato se inserte por sí solo? Eso sería mediante un trigger al INSERT. ¿O quieres manejarlo tú manualmente? Allí sí tendrías que crear y llamar a un procedimiento almacenado.

Comment: si al momento de que todos las fechas ya esten registradas hacer una busqueda que muestre los que no estan, creo que tengo que hacer el procedimiento almacenado , tienes algun codigo que pueda ayudarme en mostrarme la que no esten

Comment: Código así hecho no tengo, pero la idea que se me ocurre es que hagas un ciclo FOR en ese procedimiento, con un incremento de 5 minutos a una variable tipo DATETIME, y así vas preguntando si dicha fecha (variable) existe en un tabla, y si no existe, la insertas... es una idea muy a la rápida :o

Comment: voy a intentar hacerlo con un ciclo for desde el php o desde el mysql en si si me permite hacer el for en el mysql para que incremente cada 5 minutos el datetime , tienes un correo si me funciona correcto o si encuentro una solucion te envio el codigo , esa parte suele ser importante

Comment: si vas a hacer un intento, sería bueno que copiaras el código acá mismo, editando tu pregunta, así más personas te pueden dar su consejo ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una forma posible forma de resolverlo es si cuentas con todas las fechas, horas y minutos dentro del rango que quieras consultar. Si no tienes esta "tabla" físicamente hablando podrías llegar a generarla armando una secuencia.

```
SELECT '2017-01-01 00:00:00' + INTERVAL 5 * SEQ.row MINUTE AS Fecha
      FROM (SELECT  @row := @row + 1 as row 
                    FROM  (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t
                    CROSS JOIN (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t2
                    CROSS JOIN (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t3 
                    CROSS JOIN (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t4 
                    CROSS JOIN (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t5
                    CROSS JOIN (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t6 
                    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row:=0) t7
      ) SEQ
```

Esto te generará una consulta de 1.000.000 filas con cada fecha desde el `2017-01-01 00:00:00` en intervalos de 5 minutos, agregando más `CROSS JOIN` podrás generar más filas si así lo requieres.

Ahora bien si quieres usarlo solo para verificar el rango de fechas que ya tienes , podrías únicamente generar el intervalo de la fecha mínima y máxima de `fechaprueba`

```
SELECT T.Fecha
       FROM (SELECT LIM.Desde + INTERVAL 5 * (SEQ.row - 1) MINUTE AS Fecha
                FROM (SELECT MIN(Fecha) AS Desde,
                             MAX(Fecha) AS Hasta
                             FROM pruebafecha
                      ) LIM
                INNER JOIN (SELECT  @row := @row + 1 as row
                              FROM  (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t1
                              CROSS JOIN (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t2
                              CROSS JOIN (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t3 
                              CROSS JOIN (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t4 
                              CROSS JOIN (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t5
                              CROSS JOIN (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t6 
                              CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row:=0) t7

                     ) SEQ
                 WHERE LIM.Desde + INTERVAL 5 * (SEQ.row - 1) MINUTE <= LIM.Hasta
       ) T 
       LEFT JOIN pruebafecha P
            ON P.Fecha = T.Fecha
       WHERE P.Fecha IS NULL;
```

Comment: como podria crear esa tabla, en la parte de mysqlmyadmin tengo que crear la tabla primero y insertarlo?

Comment: La tabla no existe, Jose, la idea de Patricio es que llames a un "select" que emulará tu tabla de fechas de referencia :O

Comment: Eso, eso.. ;-) @quinqui

Comment: lo hice pero solo muestra hasta el 2017-02-04 suponiendo que generaria todo del año 2017 de enero hasta diciembre no

Comment: @Josecarlos, un año completo son 105.120 grupos de 5 minutos, la consulta que te pasé solo genera 10,000 registros, hay que agregar más `CROSS JOINS` como te explicaba antes para generar más filas. Ahora edito la pregunta, para que tengas el ejemplo para el

Comment: hablo de generar aproximada mente mas de 100 mil registros para poder comparar todas las fechas del año,

Comment: claro esta bien

Comment: esos serian hasta el mes 7

Comment: agrege hasta el numero 12 solo que queda cargando y ya no pasa de hay

Comment: ya te entendi, otra pregunta como puedo ponerla en mi tabla y que haga lo segundo que pusiste

Comment: Ahí edité la segunda consulta para que te quede completa. Saludos.

Comment: hay un detalle el objetivo es mostrar la fecha 2018/03/01 0:10 solamente pero me atrae todas las fechas que no encontro

Comment: @Josecarlos en ese caso quita la clausula  `WHERE P.Fecha IS NULL`

Comment: sigue con lo mismo muestra muchisimas fechas

Comment: solo tengo esos 3 registros y lo aplico y muestra miles de fechas

Comment: esta bien con el where solo el detalle que despues de la fecha muestra mas hay algo para limitar esa parte que por ejemplo que llegue hasta mi ultimo registro la fecha dada

Comment: @Josecarlos, la idea es que deberías adaptar la secuencia de acuerdo a tus necesidades, por ejemplo generar la secuencia entre la fecha mínima y máxima de `pruebafecha`, ahí edite la segunda consulta para que veas como se hace.