# ¿Cómo desplegar los días en los que no existen registros en MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Tengo la siguiente tabla llamada **empleados**:

| empleado | nombre |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | Juan |
| 102 | Alejandra |
| 103 | Ruth |

Y la tabla llamada **registros**:

| empleado | asistencia |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | 2021-12-01 |
| 101 | 2021-12-02 |
| 101 | 2021-12-07 |

Supongamos que busco desplegar en número de empleado, nombre y los días del mes en los que hubo faltas entre el 2021-12-01 y el 2021-12-07 (teniendo en cuenta que los días 05 y 06 son fin de semana); en ese caso, el resultado sería el siguiente:

| empleado | nombre | faltas |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Juan | 4,5 |

¿Cómo obtengo ese resultado?

Hasta el momento he desarrollado un *query* con el que se despliegan los días del mes en los que hay asistencias. Dicho *query* es el siguiente:

```
SELECT e.empleado, 
        e.nombre,, 
        r.asistencia AS asistencia, 

FROM empleados e 
                LEFT JOIN (SELECT empleado, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT EXTRACT(DAY FROM asistencia)
ORDER BY EXTRACT(DAY FROM asistencia)) AS asistencia FROM registros 
WHERE asistencia BETWEEN '2021-12-01' AND '2021-12-07' GROUP BY empleado) r ON e.empleado = empleado
WHERE (r.no_empleado IS NOT NULL) ORDER BY nombre ASC
```

Quisiera saber cómo desplegar los días en los que hubo faltas y que no considere los fines de semana en el despliegue. Ya hice varias pruebas pero sigo estancada.

Comment: Nunca trabajé con `MariaDB` así que puede que me equivoque pero leyendo vi que existe esta función `DAYOFWEEK()` por lo que se me ocurre que puedes hacer algo como: `select * from tuTabla where asistencia is null and DAYOFWEEK() between 2 and 5 `

Comment: ¿Tienes una tabla con las fechas completas en el sistema?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho, no tengo una tabla de las fechas del año (si a eso te refieres).

Comment: Bueno, cualquier solución pasa básicamente por eso, tener o crear dinámicamente una tabla de fechas para luego hacer un left join contra ellas. Creo que esto debería responder tu pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/155626/c%c3%b3mo-obtener-fechas-consecutivas-faltantes-en-mysql/155634#155634

Comment: @PatricioMoracho, ¿y cómo se dejarían de considerar los fines de semana?

Comment: Generas todas las fechas y luego deberías chequear cada  por el "day of week" y filtrar los que son sábados o domingo.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho, muchas gracias. Tus comentarios me ayudaron bastante, pero no logro desplegar la información junto con el número de empleado y nombre. ¿Sería con un LEFT JOIN? Por ahora sólo logro desplegar una columna con los días en los que hubo faltas de un empleado en particular.

Comment: El from debiera ser sobre empleado, luego haces un join a tu tabla con todas la fechas, con un `ON 1 = 1` para que le toquen todas las fechas a cada empleado, y por último un Join a tu tabla de asistencias relacionando Empleado y Fecha

Comment: @PatricioMoracho, esta es la query que realicé pero no consigo el resultado: ```SELECT u.no_empleado, u.nombre, c.fecha AS fecha FROM usuarios u CROSS JOIN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT fecha) AS fecha FROM calendario WHERE fecha BETWEEN '2021-12-01' AND '2021-12-07') c
LEFT JOIN events e ON c.fecha = e.start_event WHERE e.start_event BETWEEN '2021-12-01' AND '2021-12-07'```. Realicé una tabla calendario para simplificar la consulta, pero sigo sin éxito

Comment: Primer tema, el `WHERE` está de más. por que ya estás filtrando un período  desde la selección de fechas de tu tabla `calendario ` y segundo tema, no entiendo por que haces un `GROUP_CONCAT` si en `calendario` solo tienes fechas únicas y secuenciales simplemente selecciona `fecha`